# Capture request and replay later?

Tags: laravel

For debugging purpose, we have a long form with lots of fields and file upload field included.

We found that we each time fill the fields and chose the file and hit post again and again..

Can we capture the request and just play it when we need to? instead of filling the form over and over again each time?

Is there a recommend tool for this?

Comment: options are: postman to send the http request, lastpass to autofill the form and more

Comment: but how to replay it?

Comment: ah, autofill, then submit, I will check lastpass.. thanks

Comment: yes, another option can be using Laravel Dusk to emulate user behaviour

Comment: Selenium, [etc](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/27199/selenium-alternatives)?